# Backbone js help me get at my JSON array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I'm currently going through a backbone.js tutorial and instead of using the suggested REST service I'm using one from my company as a real-world example. The problem is that the tutorial uses a very simple JSON return from the REST server like this:

```
{
    "name":"Brian"
    "age":52
},
    "name":"Mary"
    "age":"27"
}
... etc.
```

My own data contains arrays of this type:

```
{
    "records":20,
    "customers": [{name:"Simon", age:27},{name:"Mary", age:28}... etc.]
}
```

I want to get at 'customers' in this case. I believe I can use parse: within a Model for this but this tutorial uses only a Collection and renders that out to the template. Can I do this with just a Collection? Or should I make a Model and use parse:?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a collection -- just override [`Collection.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse).  This is the function that Backbone calls to convert the raw AJAX response into model attributes.  In your case, you just need it to return `response.customers` instead of the raw response:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.customers;
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot percieve any difference after doing this. I implemented the override and there are no errors, but the template side is still outputting a blank row on my results table. Logging the success handler shows that I have an object with length: 1 and models: Array[1]. If I drill down at the console level I eventually get to see the data, but the template code <% blah.get('name') %> returns blank. It does seem to print a row though, just can't get at the data

Comment: Re-reading this I didn't mean to imply that your solution was wrong and actually just knowing that you can use that parse function in a controller is great. It makes sense and looks as if it *should* work. Also, my template has <%= not the improper syntax above

Comment: This ended up working. The mistakes (surprise!) were down to my dodgy coding! Many thanks for the info